# Rendering a Request Target Portlet from an Action event

Tags: jsf, weblogic, portlet

I have PortletA and PortletB. Both are java portlets and after I click a button in PortletA, I need to render PortletB(render PortletB in the sense I need to make it as request target, i.e isRequestTargetted must be true) .
  Please let me know, how to do it from the processAction method with an example.

```
processAction(ActionRequest req, ActionResponse res)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need some basic portlet communication, either through an event or a public render parameter. I've only used WebSphere Portal do these, so I don't feel confident guiding you through a WebLogic example, but a quick Google search gave me this documentation that you can read through. I imagine it should provide you with what you need.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13218_01/wlp/docs81/ipcguide/index.html